# nginx frontend over https and backend over http

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx acting as a reverse proxy in front of a webserver running Wordpress.
I'm not really sure if my problem is nginx, php or WordPress so I'm asking for help.

I have an nginx server running in Docker which acts as a reverse proxy.
Behind this server there is a webserver, also running in Docker, running WordPress.

This all works fine when running over http. But I'm going over to https and I can't get this to work properly.

I get "mixed-mode" messages saying that style sheets and scripts are blocked because they are served over https.
In WordPress I have added the following as seen [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/#using-a-reverse-proxy) to `wp-config.php`:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

I have also changed this:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://www.example.com');
```

I have also changed everything in the database that refers to `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

When I enter https://www.example.com I get 1 "mixed-content" warning about a style sheet being loaded over http even though there is one style sheet loaded just fine.

[image: mixed-content]

And if I enter https://www.example.com/wp-admin I get a lot of mixed content for style sheets and scripts.

[image: wp-admin]

All thses links are reachable over https but somehow they are still being served over http.
I've search every file and everything in the database and I can't find any references to http://example.com anywhere.

**This is the reverse proxy:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
    
server {
  listen        443 ssl;
  server_name   www.example.com example.com;

  ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/private/example.com/example.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/private/example.com/example.com.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://10.0.100.10:8082;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl         on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
  }
}
```

**And this is the backend**

```
server {
    server_name _;

    listen 80;

    root /var/www/myapp;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/back-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/back-error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-domain:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Can anyone understand why this is happening and where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you are passing the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP header to your FastCGI backend with this configuration. Can you try this one?

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-domain:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $http_x_forwarded_proto if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
```

If it doesn't help, add your `fastcgi_params` file contents to the question.

**Update**

There is a way to do it without altering the `wp-config.php` at all:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $fastcgi_https {
    https   on;
    default $https;
}
server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-domain:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $http_x_forwarded_proto if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https if_not_empty;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! It didn't help but it got me thinking. I had put the ´$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';´ stuff on the bottom of wp-config.php so I tried to put it in the beginning and now it's working..

Comment: Couldn't it be a cached response? Can you check it from incognito mode? What happens if you force `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';` without the `if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)` check?